# Python 2.7: Load a JSON file search for a value, replace it, and save as new JSON

Tags: json, python-2.7, search, recursion, load

As mentioned in the title, i'm trying to make a simple py script that can be run from terminal to do the following:

- Find all JSON files in current working directory and nested folders (this part works well)
- Load said files
- Recursively search them for a specific value or a substring
- If the value is matching, replace it with a new established value by the user
- Once finished, save all modified json files to a "converted" folder in the current directory.

That said, the issue is when i try the recursive search method posted below, since i'm pretty much new to python i would appreciate any help with this issue, what i suppose it is... either the json files i'm using or the search method i'm employing.

Simplifying the issue, the value i search for never matches with anything inside the object, be that a key or purely some string value. Tried multiple methods to perform a recursive search but can't get a match.

For example: taking in account the sample json, i want to replace the value "selectable_parts" or "static_parts" or even deeper in the structure "1h_mod310_door_00" but seems like my method of searching can't reach this value in "object[object][children][0][children][5][name]" (hope this helps).

Sample JSON: (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2-Bn2b0ujjVdW5YVGg3REg3OWs)

---

```
"""KEYWORD REPLACING MODULE."""
import os
import json

# functions
def get_files():
    """lists files"""
    exclude = set(['.vscode', 'sample'])
    json_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd(), topdown=True):
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith('.json'):
                json_files.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return json_files

def load_files(json_files):
    """works files"""
    for js_file in json_files:
        with open(js_file) as json_file:
            loaded_json = json.load(json_file)
            replace_key_value(loaded_json, os.path.basename(js_file))

def write_file(data_file, new_file_name):
    """writes the file"""
    if not os.path.exists('converted'):
        os.makedirs('converted')
    with open('converted/' + new_file_name, 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data_file, json_file)

def replace_key_value(js_file, js_file_name):
    """replace and initiate save"""
    recursive_replace(js_file, SKEY, '')
    # write_file(js_file, js_file_name)

def recursive_replace(data, match, repl):
    """search for needed value and replace its value"""
    for key, value in data.items():
        if value == match:
            print data[key]
            print "AHHHHHHHH"
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            recursive_replace(value, match, repl)

# main
print "\n" + '- on ' + os.getcwd()
NEW_DIR = raw_input('Work dir (leave empty if current): ')
if not NEW_DIR:
    print NEW_DIR
    NEW_DIR = os.getcwd()
else:
    print NEW_DIR
    os.chdir(NEW_DIR)

# get_files()
JS_FILES = get_files()
print '- files on ' + os.getcwd()
# print "\n".join(JS_FILES)
SKEY = raw_input('Value to search: ')
RKEY = raw_input('Replacement value: ')
load_files(JS_FILES)
```

Comment: You seem to have left out some words. The issue is what?

Comment: I'll edit the issue, but simply put the issue is that when i search the object from the loaded json file, and try to match the value with the search parameter it never matches.

I can navigate and print the object but the value never matches the parameter to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the way i navigated the json obj because the method didn't considerate if it was a dict or a list (i believe...).

So to answer my own question here's the recursive search i'm using to check the values:

```
def get_recursively(search_dict, field):
    """
    Takes a dict with nested lists and dicts,
    and searches all dicts for a key of the field
    provided.
    """
    fields_found = []

    for key, value in search_dict.iteritems():

        if key == field:
            print value
            fields_found.append(value)

        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            results = get_recursively(value, field)
            for result in results:
                if SEARCH_KEY in result:
                    fields_found.append(result)

        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    more_results = get_recursively(item, field)
                    for another_result in more_results:
                        if SEARCH_KEY in another_result:
                            fields_found.append(another_result)

    return fields_found
    # write_file(js_file, js_file_name)
```

Hope this helps someone.